# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header despite specifying allowedOrigins

Tags: cors, spring-cloud

Is my allowedOrigins specified correctly?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        args:
          retries: 3
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
            - PUT
            - DELETE
            - OPTIONS
```

I still get the error:

```
... blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Edit: Client code is here:

```
export const restClient = (jwtToken = null) => {
   const nonSecureOptions = {
       headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
   };

   const secureOptions = {
       headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Content-Encoding': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
       },
   };

   const getDefaultOptions = (jwtToken) => jwtToken ? secureOptions : nonSecureOptions;

   return {
       get: (url, options = {}) => axios.get(url, { ...getDefaultOptions(jwtToken), ...options }),
       post: (url, data, options = {}) => axios.post(url, data, { ...getDefaultOptions(jwtToken), ...options }),
       put: (url, data, options = {}) => axios.put(url, data, { ...getDefaultOptions(jwtToken), ...options }),
       delete: (url, options = {}) => axios.delete(url, { ...getDefaultOptions(jwtToken), ...options })
   };
```

};

and it's being called like

```
const response = await restClient(token).get(myurl)
```

Comment: Show the frontend code responsible for sending the request to your server.

Comment: @jub0bs Should be there now.

Comment: You need to allow the `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

Comment: Thank you @jub0bs This was the problem.  I did not allow any headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

1. you're explicitly attaching the `Authorization` header (the one and only so-called [*non-wildcard request-header name*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-non-wildcard-request-header-name)) to your request , and
2. [you're specifying `application/json` as the value of the `Content-Type` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests),

you need to also explicitly allow those headers:

```yaml
globalcors:
  corsConfigurations:
    '[/**]':
      allowedOrigins: "*"
      allowedMethods:
        - GET
        - POST
        - PUT
        - DELETE
        - OPTIONS
      allowedHeaders:
        - Authorization
        - Content-Type
```